# Use awk output as variable for string comparison

Tags: macos, shell, awk

I'm filtering the output of `ifconfig` on a macOS (High Sierra) to trigger an action using a simple if statement, though the action isn't triggered although the corresponding strings appear to match (when tested with `echo`).

When the script is run, if the network `en1` is active, the expected action is to print OK.

I tried:

- `printf "%s"` in the `awk` command
- using a double (and simple) quote for `"active"`
- holding `active` in a variable for the comparison
- replacing `` en1_status=`...` `` by `en1_status=$(...)`

without success.

```
#!/bin/bash
en1_status=`ifconfig en1 | grep "status: " | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$en1_status" = active ]; then
    echo OK
fi
```

And `$en1_status` seems to match `active`:

```
echo $en1_status
active
```

Comment: Please do mention what is the expected output in your post too?

Comment: In relation to behaviour, the script does look like it sets the `ALL_PROXY` variable in the case of `en1` being active. However you're not explaining what you're expecting to have happen. I'm speculating that the issue is that you expect the `ALL_PROXY` variable to be set after the command returns; which won't happen because variables inherit downwards, and don't propagate back to the caller.

Comment: Try quoting 'active in your test and on the variable in ALL_PROXY, i.e. 'http://proxy.ext:8080'

Comment: @Petesh I updated the question, to stick to the actual problem I have. The problem is about the string comparison.

Comment: @gregory I tried `"active"` and `'active'` as well.

Comment: @Petesh Though you have a point regarding the `export`...

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` to log execution. `echo` isn't trustworthy -- you can easily have strings that look the same but aren't.

Comment: BTW, `grep | awk` is pointless, as `awk` can do everything `grep` can and more; `en1_status=$(ifconfig en1 | awk '/status: / { print $2 }')` would do the same thing, without an extra process in the pipeline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the `bash -x` & the recommendation with `awk`. It works if I use `awk` for both actions. Still I wonder why it works for @mjuarez & not for me using both `grep` & `awk`.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if you have your `grep` configured to do color highlighting even when its output is to a FIFO? That would explain why switching to `awk` fixes things (it *should* just be a performance tweak, rather than a fix).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right! I was just investigating the problem further by using another version of `grep` (brew) and the `GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated` message led me to this. I was about to answer my question, but I'll let you do it then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177975/discussion-between-marc-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This generally means that you've got nonprintable characters -- like syntax highlighting, or DOS newlines -- in your variable.

One easy way this can happen is if you've got your `grep` instance set to always insert color codes, as with `--color=always` rather than the default (safer) `--color=auto`.

To track this down, compare the output of the following commands:

```
printf '%s' "$en1_status" | xxd
printf '%s' inactive | xxd
```

You can also moot `grep`'s configuration by letting `awk` do the searching:

```
en1_status=$(ifconfig en1 | awk '/status: / { print $2 }')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works on MacOS, if you double quote the right hand side of the `if` comparison (I replaced `inactive` for my local test, because that interface is not active locally for me):

```
~/> cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash
en1_status=`ifconfig en1 | grep "status: " | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$en1_status" = "inactive" ]; then
    echo OK
fi
```

And when I run it:

```
~/> ./test.sh 
OK
```

Comment: There's no need to quote the right-hand side (when it's a constant string with no syntactically-relevant characters and you're using `[ ]` rather than `[[ ]]`). Behavior is 100% identical with it unquoted. As such, while nothing you're saying here is false (I believe you that the script behaves the way you say it does!), this answer is arguably misleading, as it presents a change that can't have any impact as if it were a fix.

Comment: (I wouldn't be surprised if the OP had DOS newlines, or copied-and-pasted from a source that had them -- if instead of assigning `inactive` to their variable they're assigning `inactive$'\r'` because there's a literal carriage return at the end of the `en1_status=...` line in their code, that explains their bug, *and* explains why nobody but them can reproduce it).

Comment: It does not on mine, here is the output of the `bash-r`: ```++ ifconfig en1
++ grep 'status: '
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ en1_status='inactive'
+ '[' 'inactive' = inactive ']'```

Comment: @Marc, interesting -- since `set -x` thinks that it needs to quote that, there's something nonprintable, yet it still isn't rendering visibly. What's the output from `LC_ALL=C printf '%q\n' "$en1_status"`? Or, to be oven more paranoid/cautious (in a way that doesn't depend on the shell release/version you're running), you can compare `printf '%s' "$en1_status" | xxd` to `printf '%s' inactive | xxd`